# theme_links() override has no effect

Tags: 7, theming, routes

So I want menus to output in a custom way. I would not output the following HTML.

```
<ul attributes>
    <li attributes>
       <a href="foo">foo</a>
    </li>
    <li attributes>
       <a href="bar">bar</a>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

I would replace it with the following one.

```
<nav attributes>
   <a attributes href="foo">foo</a>
   <a attributes href="bar">bar</a>
</nav>
```

So I put in the template.php file the following function (my theme is called mFAC).

```
function mFAC_links($variables) {
    // custom stuff
}
```

I am starting with a light alteration, but nothing seems to have any effect. I cleared the cache.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Did you rebuild the theme registry == clear caches ? And BTW, your function should `return $output`. Does it ?

Comment: So far I have just copied and pasted the function from theme.inc with only a slight variation to test that its having an effect. I cleared the caches and it does return $output

Comment: How are your links output in your `tpl.php` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use YOUR_THEME_menu_tree() for this. You can target it to a specific menu using YOUR_THEME_menu_tree__MENU_NAME(). Make sure you return the variable after alterations. Refer [this](http://drupal.org/node/254940#theme-suggestions-for-menus) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the menu wrapper in this manner:

```
function YOURTHEME_menu_tree__MENU_NAME($variables) {
  return '<nav class="menu'.$variables['delta'].'">' . $variables['tree'] . '</nav>';
}
```